# Ensemble method with Blackbox Classifiers

Tags: classifier, ensemble, meta-learning

I have few pre-trained blackbox models that are used for classification tasks. I want to know what is the best way to combine these models into a single classifier that does not require any re-training of these models.

Edit: The models take input $X$, and predicts a single class $\hat{Y}$ out of several possible classes. Some models are able to predict correct class in some instances of $X_i$ while other predict wrong class and vice-versa. My goal is to use these outputs $\hat{Y}_i$  as input features to new meta-modal which is trained on these array of predicted classes as input along with ground-truth $Y$.

$$M(\hat{Y}_i) \rightarrow Y$$

Two options were [majority voting classifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier.html) and [stacking](https://machinelearningmastery.com/stacking-ensemble-machine-learning-with-python/). However this methods require to retrain underlying classifiers. My classifiers are blackbox so it there a better way rather then simple max voting?

Comment: How do you know the models have different skills? Any other details you can share? Like is one an SVM blackbox and another a neural net blackbox? That can make a difference for how an ensemble exploits their respective strengths. As stated, the OP suggests that your current task is to train a model that accepts N + 6 features, viewing each model output as just-another-feature. // Tell us about the inputs and the outputs. Does it just emit a hard `0` / `1` classification labels, or do you get a soft 0 .. 1 probability? Are the inputs categorical or continuous?

Comment: @J_H the are transformer based blackboxes. The input to the model is an array of features `X` and the models perform mult-class classification `y^`. In some instances some models predict correct class while others predict wrong class and vice versa so I want to combine them by training a meta-model so that it captures such short-comings of the model based on the outputs as its input features `y^`s and picks correct output from it. The model emits hard classification. I get the concrete label in the end

Comment: @J_H I have updated the question.

Comment: That’s too bad, that we get a hard classification output. If the transformers output a probability, a confidence in the results, that would make it easier for the meta-model to steer its response toward   results having greater confidence. // Notice that a transformer which outputs a single classification drawn from K different classes, could also output K different boolean values with associated confidence. That is, the output would be arg max of the K different probabilities. This would be more suitable as input to a meta-model.

Comment: @J_H This makes sense. I took different approach by encoding the classes to numerical values. I believe you method of utilizing confidence could have been much better, but the model doesnt output confidence levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more reviewing I came across the following solution:

[image]

So basically Logistic regression's input is supposed to be numerical values, while the Neural networks (NNs) that I have gave string-based classes. I simply encoded each class to numeric values, (I had 10 classes so 1,2,3..10) and fed these as input to "multi-class logistic regression" and I was able to furthur refine the output from several NNs closer to the ground-truth.